# C# StreamWriter / NetworkStream / TcpClient / Not sending data after idle for +5 min

Tags: c#, tcpclient, streamwriter, networkstream

I setup a `StreamWriter`/`StreamReader` connection from a `NetworkStream` to control a piece of test equipment.  The underlying connection is TCP.

In this particular instance, this connection remains idle for several minutes.  After +5 minutes pass, when I call `streamWriter.writeLine(...)`, then flush, no data is sent out from my computer to the test equipment  (Watching packets on wireshark).  Before and during the idle time, no packets are exchanged.  No FIN, or RST packets, etc...

Debugging my `streamWriter` object, it appears to still be valid (`connected = true`, etc...)

I'm having issues identifying what portion of my `StreamWriter`/`NetworkStream`/`TcpClient` object is timing out or closing w/out sending a FIN or RST message to formally close the connection.

Here is an abbreviated version of the code that is failing:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        TcpClient client;
        NetworkStream networkStream;
        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader;
        System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter;
        string outputString;

        client = new TcpClient("555.555.555.555", 5025);
        client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
        networkStream = client.GetStream();
        streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);
        streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);

        //This section works fine, every time
        streamWriter.WriteLine("*IDN?\n");     //Ask for equipment identification
        streamWriter.Flush();
        outputString = streamReader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("First Attempt: Connected to: {0}", outputString);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(301000);  //Simulate idle connection time

        //The read in this section fails if the sleep above is longer than 5 minutes
        streamWriter.WriteLine("*IDN?\n");     //Ask for equipment identification
        streamWriter.Flush();
        outputString = streamReader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Second Attempt: Connected to: {0}", outputString);
}
```

The error is found when I try to read the response back from what I wrote out to the equipment.  Because the equipment never saw my request, I get a read timeout error.

If I change my sleep to something less than 5 minutes, everything works fine.

I've looked into implementing some kind of keep alive on the socket, but my understanding is that natively, a TCP connection will remain open until either end closes it.

I also don't believe this is a 3rd party networking issue as Wireshark shows that no FIN or RST messages have been sent/received and my attempt to write out a message after 5 minutes is not seen by Wireshark, which is also running on my computer.

I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on my Windows 7 computer, if that helps.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.  Please also let me know if I need to explain any details further or clarify something.

Comment: I've had the same problem. It's not a problem with your code. Something between the devices is cleaning up idle connections (probably a stateful firewall?). Adding a keepalive (10 minutes was adequate in my case) was the only solution I could find.

Comment: worth trying *just in case* - set `NoDelay` on the tcp-client

Comment: With some additional digging, I disabled my anti-virus software 'Symantec' and could no longer re-create the issue.  It would appear that the policy on my computer, set up by the IT department, will shut down an idle connection.  In efforts to play nice with the policy, I'm going to implement a simple timing check where if the last time the connection was used was over a certain time ago, I will close and re-open the connection.

Comment: That said, I did some quick Google searching but could not find any guidelines regarding idle timelines and the use of socket connections... know of any?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by implementing a time check that would close and re-establish the connection if more than a few minutes went by with no traffic.  This is because the anti-virus software running on the host computer was proactively, yet w/out notification, terminating idle socket connections.